# Как получить значения внутри div с помощью onclick на него?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

У меня есть 5 `<div>` с классом `specific-letter` в которых по одной букве.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также у меня есть код, которий делает что-то когда я кликаю на `<div>` с классом `specific-letter`.

```
let click = () => {
 let letters = document.getElementsByClassName("specific-letter");
 let result = document.getElementById("names");
 let valueOnClick = document.getElementsByClassName("specific-letter").innerHTML;
 for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
      letters[i].addEventListener("click", () => {

           console.log(valueOnClick); 

      }, false);
   }
 }
click();
```

Почему я в консоли получаю `undefined`? И как мне засунуть букву в переменную?

HTML:

```
<div class="specific-letter" onclick="click()">y</div>
```

Comment: Потому что `getElementsByClassName` возвращает массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так попробуйте. И посмотрите на результат в консоли

```
let click = () => {
 let letters = document.getElementsByClassName("specific-letter");
 
 
 for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
      letters[i].addEventListener("click", clickDiv, false);
   }
 }

function clickDiv(){

           console.log(this.innerHTML); 

      }
click();
```

Я бы сделал немного по другому.

```
 let letters = document.getElementsByClassName("specific-letter");
 
 let letterArray = letters.map(letter=>letter.innerHTML);
 console.log(letterArray);
 for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
      letters[i].addEventListener("click", click, true);
   }
 

function click(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(this.innerHTML); 
}
```

Comment: Получилось, но почему то 2 раза консолит...

Comment: Попробуйте второй вариант

Comment: Не проблема сунуть в переменную

Comment: все все, я уже догадался, тупой вопрос)